# Como não deixar uma Animação em CSS parar mesmo apos o mouse sair de cima do elemento

Tags: html5, css3, animação, keyframes

Tenho uma `div` que tem uma animação no `:hover`, porém se o usuário tirar o mouse de cima da `div` antes da animação terminar ela corta pela metade e não termina.

Tentei fazer um efeito de "spot light" que atravessa a imagem da esquerda para a direita no mouse `:hover`, mas se o mouse sair de cima a animação ela é interrompida de forma brusca. Gostaria que esse "spot light" continuasse atravessando a imagem até o final mesmo se o *mouse* sair de cima da `div`.

Veja o problema acontecendo quando faz o `:hover` e retira o *mouse* logo em seguida antes de *spot* atravessar a imagem por completo.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/700/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.box:hover::after,
.box:hover::before {
    content: "";
    width: 40%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    transform: skewX(-5deg);
    left: -40%;
    animation: bgc 1000ms linear forwards;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
@keyframes bgc {
    0% {left: -40%}
    100% {left: 140%}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**OBS:** A animação só acontece uma vez a cada mouse over.

Comment: acredito q tenha q usar js mesmo....mas gostei do placecage.com e dos outros sites desse cara kkkkkk

Comment: @KarlZillner acho que vai ter que ser com JS ou jQuery mesmo, com CSS acho que não vai rolar. Até tentei com `transition` e não com `keyframes` mas tb não deu certo... OBS: Meus preferidos, PlaceCage e FillMurray XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo, conforme pedido...

```js
$(function(){
  $('#box').on('mouseover', function(){
    var mv = $(this);
    mv.addClass('box');
    setTimeout(function(){
      mv.removeClass('box')
    }, 1000)
  })
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/700/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.box:after,
.box:before {
    content: "";
    width: 40%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    transform: skewX(-5deg);
    left: -40%;
    animation: bgc 1000ms linear forwards;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
@keyframes bgc {
    0% {left: -40%}
    100% {left: 140%}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" ></div>
```